# How to justify escaped proportional text inside monospaced/fixed listing?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, boxes

I have a fixed column listing on which I have escapped to LaTeX to write a proportional bit of text. The following pic illustrates what I have:

[image]

On the green box, the proportional text have perfectly aligned to the monospaced text, probably by accident, but that's exactly what I want.

On the red box, because of the subscript there, the text did not align properly to the fixed columns. (In this case, I believe the spacing should be increased so that the semicolon will align to the space above it.)

How could I justify escaped text (possibly with math mode equations) so that it would align to the closest number of fixed-width columns inside the listing?

Here's the code to reproduce the above table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\lstnewenvironment{rgxbc}
  {\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fixed,
    escapeinside={@}{@}
    }
  }
  {}

\subsection{Relation to NFAs}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{*3l}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{Expression}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{NFA}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{Bytecode}} \\
    \midrule
    $\texttt{e}_{1}\texttt{e}_{2}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
     @\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}_{1}$@;
     @\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}_{2}$@;
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \hline
    $\texttt{e}_{1}| \texttt{e}_{2}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
     SPL .L1, .L2;
.L1: @\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}_{1}$@;
     JMP .L3;
.L2: @\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}_{2}$@;
.L3:
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \hline
    $\texttt{e?}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
     SPL .L1, .L2;
.L1: @\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}$@;
.L2:
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \hline
    $\texttt{e+}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
.L1: @\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}$@;
     SPL .L1, .L2;
.L2:
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \hline
    $\texttt{e*}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
.L1: SPL .L2, .L3;
.L2: @\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}$@;
     JMP .L1;
.L3:
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force all the escaped code into a box a size a multiple of the listings fixed column width

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{{%
\setbox0\hbox{{#1}}%
\count0=\wd0
\divide\count0 by \dimexpr\lst@widthfixed\relax
\dimen0=\count0 \dimexpr\lst@widthfixed\relax
\ifdim\dimen0<\wd0 \advance\dimen0 \lst@widthfixed\fi
\makebox[\dimen0][l]{\usebox0}}}%

\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\lstnewenvironment{rgxbc}
  {\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fixed,
    escapeinside={@}{@}
    }
  }
  {}



\subsection{Relation to NFAs}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{*3l}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{Expression}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{NFA}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{Bytecode}} \\
    \midrule
    $\texttt{e}_{1}\texttt{e}_{2}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
     @\zz{\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}_{1}$}@;
     @\zz{\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}_{2}$}@;
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \hline
    $\texttt{e}_{1}| \texttt{e}_{2}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
     SPL  .L1, .L2;
.L1: @\zz{\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}_{1}$}@;
     JMP  .L3;
.L2: @\zz{\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}_{2}$}@;
.L3:
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \hline
    $\texttt{e?}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
     SPL  .L1, .L2;
.L1: @\zz{\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}$}@;
.L2:
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \hline
    $\texttt{e+}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
.L1: @\zz{\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}$}@;
     SPL  .L1, .L2;
.L2:
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \hline
    $\texttt{e*}$ &
    ...
    &
    \begin{rgxbc}
.L1: SPL  .L2, .L3;
.L2: @\zz{\textnormal{\textit{code for }}$\texttt{e}$}@;
     JMP  .L1;
.L3:
    \end{rgxbc}
    \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```